# Magento coupon code functionality

Tags: php, magento

Magento coupon code functionality

I want display related coupon code in product listing page in magento. Is it possible or not.

Comment: What do you mean by related coupon code?

Answer (score 0):

hey your question is not enough to understand what exactly you want to accomplish and what do you mean by related coupon code please provide descriptive question so i can understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to show the Catalog Coupon code in your product listing page? If yes, please see details below.

While creating a coupon you have an option to select a `Related Banners` which can be added via CMS -> Banners. This banner is then shown on all pages.

If you want to add it specific to any page, you can do that using the Static Block & widgets. 
1.  Create a new Static Block using CMS -> Static Block, add that Coupon code in the Content
2.  Then add a new Widget of `CMS Static Block` type
3.  Select that Static block and select the page in which you want to show the same using the `Layout Updates` section